# I am using tongue and groove planks for a desk. What's the best substrate to use?

Tags: desk, tongue-and-groove

I am using tongue and groove planks for a desk. What's the best substrate to use?

Comment: If the planks are thick enough and the desk small enough, a couple of trestles would do.

Comment: This question might be more at home in the Woodworkers discussion.

Comment: Yeah, WW.SE will have good Q&A for this, but it'll probably be flagged for more detail. Lumber dimension, intended desk span and construction, and intended use are all pretty much required for advice on a design. If you provid even a rough sketch you might even get immediate answers.

Answer (score -1):

best substrate would be 3/4 or 19mm baltic birch ply, or as a second choice, 3/4 maple ply.

Comment: not sure i agree.  the op asked a simple question and i gave him a simple answer.  i am not really interested in your opinion.

Comment: The message you're responding to isn't an opinion, it's the guideline of the site.\

Comment: still dont agree.  if you ask an ambiguous question, why would i respond with anything other than an approximate answer.  otherwise i am just wasting time speculating on what the possibilities are for the op's intent

Comment: I mean, that was an automated message, because your message WAS SHORT.

Comment: 3/4 in plywood is total overkill in most cases. But we don't even know what size this desk is, what the spans will be, or what it'll be used for.